# Prove that if $H$ is a unique subgroup of order $|H|$ then $H$ is a characteristic subgroup.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group and $H\leq G$. $H$ is a unique subrgroup of order $|H|$.

Prove that $H$ is a characteristic subgroup.

I tried to show by contradiction that if $\phi (h)\not \in H$ then I can find a subgroup of order $H$ (I was looking for come cyclic subgroup) where $\phi (h)$ is in that subgroup but couldn't make it so far. any hints?

Comment: If $\varphi$ is an automorphism of $G$, then prove that $\varphi(H)$ is a subgroup and $|\varphi(H)|  = |H|$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the image of $H$ under any automorphism of $G$ must have the same order as $H$. therefore it must be $H$. hence $H$ is a characteristic subgroup of $G$